Telefram bot bot.polling() do not work when I use button
type here

I have to send a list of name and status of along with buttons for each name.
I use the code below but whenever I click on button on message sent on telegram, It haver error name: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
keyboard = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=4)
buttons = []
for index, row in lost_info.iterrows():
    htmlstring += '...'
    button_text = f"{row['pop_name']}"
    button = InlineKeyboardButton(str(button_text), callback_data=str(button_text))
    buttons.append(button)
    if len(buttons) % 4 == 0:  # Create a new row after every 4 buttons
        keyboard.row(*buttons)
        buttons = []
keyboard.row(*buttons)  
bot.send_photo(chat_id, photo=open('page.png', 'rb'),reply_markup=keyboard)
def detail_message(content):
    return f"You clicked {content}"
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True) 
def callback(call):
    content = call.data
    bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, text=detail_message(content))



ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_17640\2729174179.py in ?()
36
37 if lostnum1h > 0 :
38     print(lostnum1h)
39     # Proceed with polling if lostnum1h has data
---> 40     bot.polling()
41 else:
42     print(lostnum1h)
43     # Handle the case where there's no data in lostnum1h (optional)
c:\Users\Yen Cassie FPT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\telebot_init_.py in ?(self, non_stop, skip_pending, interval, timeout, long_polling_timeout, logger_level, allowed_updates, none_stop, restart_on_change, path_to_watch)
1174
1175         logger.info('Starting your bot with username: [@%s]', self.user.username)
1176
1177         if self.threaded:
-> 1178             self.__threaded_polling(non_stop=non_stop, interval=interval, timeout=timeout, long_polling_timeout=long_polling_timeout,
1179                                     logger_level=logger_level, allowed_updates=allowed_updates)
1180         else:
1181             self.__non_threaded_polling(non_stop=non_stop, interval=interval, timeout=timeout, long_polling_timeout=long_polling_timeout,
c:\Users\Yen Cassie FPT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\telebot_init_.py in ?(self, non_stop, interval, timeout, long_polling_timeout, logger_level, allowed_updates)
1249                 if not handled:
1250                     polling_thread.stop()
...
1578             f"The truth value of a {type(self).name} is ambiguous. "
1579             "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."
1580         )
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
Output is truncated. View as a scrollable element or open in a text editor. Adjust cell output settings...

How can I send a message with button and send back the information appropriate with that content?

